# Connecting a mapped drive letter in Windows service

Tags: delphi, windows-services, unc, network-drive, mapped-drive

I'm writing a Windows service (*Delphi XE2*) that calls functions in a 3rd party `COM` library.  The core of the `COM` library is quite old and requires that a drive letter is mapped to the location of its data files.  It absolutely does not work with `UNC` paths.  In my service I'm connecting the drive letter when the service starts to ensure it has it available.  I'm using the `WNetAddConnection2` API call, and checking the return value.  The drive is being connected successfully, unless the drive letter is already in use (`ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED`) but in either case the COM functions operate fine.  The problems I'm having stem from when the service is stopped.  If I disconnect the drive when the service stops (`WNetCancelConnection2`) and other applications/services on the server are using the drive letter then they are affected and lose their connection.  However if I don't disconnect the drive when the service stops then the drive is 'lost' and unavailable to be connected by other services.

I'm sure this is all to do with how drive mappings are 'owned' by the session/service that creates them, but I'm not sure what the right solution is.  I'm currently starting the service under *'Local System'*.  I know Microsoft have always recommended that services do not use mapped drives but I just don't have a choice.  Has anybody come across this problem before and have any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm currently starting the service under 'Local System'

Try different user account.

Due to security reasons in Windows Local System is kept Local - IOW banned from network access

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Dedicate a user account for the connection* ;
2. Pass this user to WNetAddConnection2;

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968426/wnetaddconnection2-from-a-windows-service).

*In a Workgroup this account must be mirrored on the destination machine + [security model on the destionation PC must be set to "Classic" using GPEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786449%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Driver letters are assigned on a per-user basis.  The only way your service's drive letter assignments can affect other apps/services is if they are all running within the same user account.  Apps do not run in the `LocalSystem` account unless they are launched by services that are running as `LocalSystem` (but then they would not be visible to the user).  So if you want to have your service's drive letter assignments be isolated to just your service, then create a dedicated user account for your service to run in.  That also gives you the ability to customize the permissions of that user account so it has network access without requiring full system access if not actually needed.