# GetNamedSecurityInfo Intermittent failure with error=2

Tags: c++, windows, acl, impersonation, ntfs

I have a C++ program running as a system service under "NT Authority\System".

The program has multiple threads, and each thread will occasionally wake up and try to load the ACL for a specified path. The problem I am running in to is that I sporadically see the GetNamedSecurityInfo() call fail with Error=2, File Not Found. The strange thing is that this call will succeed with the same path for a while, then something happens, and the call will then fail.

My Code looks like this:

```
        SE_OBJECT_TYPE dwObjectType = SE_FILE_OBJECT;
        LPTSTR szFile = _T("\\\\server\\share\\folder");
        DWORD dwError = ::GetNamedSecurityInfo(szFile, dwObjectType, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, &pDacl, 0, (void**)&pSD);
        if (dwError || !pDacl)
        {
            TRACE(_T("Error=%d\n"),dwError);
            // try it again, maybe I was impersonating a different AD user by mistake.
            ::RevertToSelf();
            dwError = ::GetNamedSecurityInfo(szFile, dwObjectType, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, &pDacl, 0, (void**)&pSD);
            TRACE(_T("Error=%d\n"),dwError);
        }
```

I've been beating my head against a wall for days on this one and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I have verified that the service has access to the \\server\share\ and also to the folder. And the folder does exist. The call works great most of the time, then will simply fail until I restart the Service.

Comment: the `\\server\share` associated with which logon session luid ? and which luid you have in token when call  *GetNamedSecurityInfo* ?

Comment: the service is logged in under "NT Authority\System". the NTFS ACL on the 'share' has Everyone with Full Rights; and the underlying directory on the C:\ being referenced by the share has an NTFS ACL with Everyone/Full Rights too.

Comment: no, you don't understand. i ask about logon session luid. `\\server\share` is visible only for some logon session. result depend from luid in your token. so i and ask - for which luid this share is created ? and which luid in your token ?

Comment: @RbMm, a UNC path should work from any logon session, shouldn't it?  I thought that if there wasn't an existing connection for the logon session, one would be created, provided the user represented by the token has access to the share.

Comment: Not sure if this is really related to your problem, but I think you should be checking for unexpected impersonation and explicitly raising an error condition, not just calling RevertToSelf() at random.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, my mistake. this not exactly depend from logon session. however not worked from *LocalSystem* ( `S-1-5-18`). when i impersonate with this token i got error `ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION`. after `RevertToSelf()` all ok. so exactly under "NT Authority\System" must and not work, but with another error.

Comment: @RbMm, that should still work as far as I can see?  Provided you're in a domain of course.  Impersonation doesn't necessarily give you access to network files but once you've reverted it ought to work just the same as if you'd never impersonated ... is this another Windows bug?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - i simply try say that under local system token `GetNamedSecurityInfo` or `CreateFile` return `ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION` while under another account i can open file, or another errors ( `ERROR_[NETWORK_]ACCESS_DENIED`). but not view `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` if file actually exist - this error really not depend from token.

Comment: [*It is not possible to connect to other PC/network resource under LocalSystem account*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385418.aspx) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968426/wnetaddconnection2-from-a-windows-service

Comment: So it turned out that some how the impersonation token became corrupt or was closed inadvertantly. RevertToSelf forced back to Local System which doesn't know about the UNC share so it accurately returned 2.

Thanks for the help, I'll close this out.

Comment: It should be noted that the comment @RbMm links to above is wrong; you *can* connect to a network resource as local system, provided the computer is joined to an Active Directory domain.  (And of course the server has to be joined to the same domain, or one with a trust relationship.)

Comment: yes, under some conditions connections from Local System work. say when share really point to the localhost. and probably with Active Directory domain - i have no knowledge here. but i be paid more attention to the error - `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. i sure that if we have problem with impersonation/account - will be another error. for example `ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION`, may be so another. let be even `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` but not `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. here something else. i be do more research here. and at first try direct open files instead call `GetNamedSecurityInfo`

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that some how the impersonation token became corrupt or was closed inadvertantly. RevertToSelf forced back to Local System which doesn't know about the UNC share so it accurately returned 2. Thanks for the help, I'll close this out.